# C# Moving a section of items within the list

Tags: c#, list

I'm finding this is a lot harder than I thought. How can I move a section of items within a List?

For example, if I have the following list:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    myList.Add(i);
}
```

This list would contain `{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }`.

How can I move sections of the List around? Say I want to move `{ 7, 8, 9 }` to the the 4th index, making it:

```
{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6 }
```

Or, say I want to move `{ 1, 2 }` in `{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }` to the 8th index, making it:

```
{ 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 8, 9 }
```

Can anyone provide some code? Something that takes 3 values like the following would be great.

```
MoveSection(insertionPoint, startIndex, endIndex)
```

Note when you remove sections from the beginning the insertion location has changed. This makes it quite a bit more difficult.

Comment: Using linked lists, this will prove to be easy. You only need to change two pointers then.

Comment: What are the memory requirements -- can you create additional lists?

Comment: Yes, you can create additional lists. I'd like it to inplace if doable but it's not necessary.

Comment: @Sebastian: You can probably post that as an answer, there are other solutions, but a linked list is a perfectly valid one (especially when the OP does not give a reason for using `List`)

Comment: @Sebastian: Please share how to do that. I'm interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this very generally for any `IEnumerable` using an iterator block relatively simply.  I always find that using the `yield return` construct solves this type of problem in a clear and concise way. Here, I've also made the method into an extension method for ease of use:

```
public static class Extension
{
   public static IEnumerable<T> MoveSection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> @this, int insertionPoint, int startIndex, int endIndex)
   {
      var counter = 0;
      var numElements = endIndex - startIndex;
      var range = Enumerable.Range(startIndex, numElements);
      foreach(var i in @this)
      {
          if (counter == insertionPoint) {
              foreach(var j in @this.Skip(startIndex).Take(numElements)) {
                  yield return j;
              }
          }
          if (!range.Contains(counter)) {
              yield return i;
          }
          counter++;
      }             
      //The insertion point might have been after the entire list:
      if (counter++ == insertionPoint) {
          foreach(var j in @this.Skip(startIndex).Take(numElements)) {
              yield return j;
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Here I use the Linq methods [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx), which are often useful.  Also, you might be interested in the `Enumerable.Range` method, which allows for easy creation of the ranges like you do with a `for` loop instead.

You can then invoke the method like so:

```
myList.MoveSection(8, 1, 3);
```

Comment: I think you're assuming the list contains only unique elements with that `.Contains`..

Comment: Ah no, I see - it should be -- and you've fixed it :P

Comment: I meant to write Contains(counter).  It is now fixed.  I am checking if the counter is in the desired range.

Comment: This method assumes it is a good idea to enumerate `IEnumerable` multiple times. This holds for `IList`, but not for every possible `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Also your invoke example does not do anything? Given that it rebuilds the sequence, not changes it. Should probably re-assign `myList`.

Comment: I just meant the new list can be accessed using `myList.MoveSection`.  If the user of the method wants to reassign the variable, so be it.  Use `myList = myList.MoveSection(8, 1, 3).ToList()`

Comment: It would be hard to do this without going over the list more than once for an `IEnumerable` in general, since the range that you want to have inserted may come after the insertion point.

Comment: Sure, I just think such methods should take a `IReadOnlyCollection` (if 4.5) at least to demonstrate that they are unsafe (might cause extreme performance hit) for general implementation of `IEnumerable`.

Comment: I'm getting the error: "The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Skip<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, int)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Comment: @rotaercz I forgot to include the type parameter on the method declaration.  I have fixed it now.

Comment: I also want to note that if you actually use this, you should add some sanity checks like checking bounds, silly inputs, etc.

Comment: Now I'm getting: The type arguments for method (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>, int, int, int)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @rotaercz If you're using some complex types with inheritance or something, you can try specifying the type parameter explicitly:  `myList.MoveSection<MyType>(8, 1, 4)`.  However, this should work without the type parameter on a list of `ints`:  `Enumerable.Rang(0, 10).MoveSection(8, 1, 4)` works for me.  What exactly are you trying to do now?

Comment: No, it's a pretty straight forward List of ints. I tried: myList.MoveSection<int>(insertionIndex, slotBegin, slotEnd);

I'm not getting the error but it didn't seem to do anything though?

Comment: if you want to set the variable to the new list, do `myList = myList.MoveSection<int>(insertionIndex, slotBegin, slotEnd).ToList()`

Comment: It did work for...
myList = myList.MoveSection<int>(4, 7, 8).ToList();

I tried the following and it didn't work though:
myList = myList.MoveSection<int>(2, 0, 3).ToList();

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31951/discussion-between-ben-reich-and-rotaercz)

Comment: @BenReich I honestly don't understand the `yield return` syntax here. Would you like to explain, please?

Comment: Found a bug, for a list that looks like this: {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}.

MoveSection<int>(10, 6, 8); // this should move the values to the end but the values that should have moved to the end just disappears. Can you please fix this?

Comment: @Sebastion  In a method that returns an `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerator`, you can use the `yield return` construct to indicate that an item should be returned.  Recall that `IEnumerables` are lazy, and so when the next element of an `IEnumerable` is requested, the method executes until it reaches a `yield return` statement, at which point control is returned to the caller.  When the next element of the `IEnumerable` is requested, control returns to the method.  Read more here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9k7k7cf0.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with creating another list, use `GetRange/AddRange` with some simple correction.
If you want to do it inplace, it would be something like this (seems to work with your use cases, but I recommend some proper unit-testing):

```
public static void MoveRange<T>(this IList<T> list, int startIndex, int count, int targetIndex) {
    var correctedStartIndex = startIndex;
    var correctedTargetIndex = targetIndex;
    for (var i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var item = list[correctedStartIndex + i];
        list.RemoveAt(correctedStartIndex + i);
        if (correctedTargetIndex > correctedStartIndex + i)
            correctedTargetIndex -= 1;

        list.Insert(correctedTargetIndex, item);            
        if (correctedStartIndex > correctedTargetIndex)
            correctedStartIndex += 1;            
    }
}
```

Note that I haven't added any validation whatsoever (range intersection with insertion point, source range being outside of the list, etc). If you are doing an extension method in a real project I advise validating all that.

Comment: This doesn't work correctly and doesn't seem to keep the correct order when I try to move a few indices from the beginning to a more higher position.

Comment: @rotaercz what inputs? I have tested with `{1, 2}` from your post and it seemed to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

OK, elaborating on my comment above, let's try an implementation as an extension method to `LinkedList<T>`:

I could not test it in any way, I just coded it in notepad.
`startIndex` = start index of section you want to move
`endIndex` = end index of section you want to move (inclusive)
`moveIndex` = index you want to move the section to. `0` = beginning of list, `list.Count` = end of list.

```
public static bool MoveSection<T>(this LinkedList<T> list, int startIndex, int endIndex, int moveIndex){
    //bounds checking
    if (startIndex < moveIndex && moveIndex < endIndex){
        return false;
    }
    if (list.Count <= startIndex || list.Count <= endIndex || list.Count+1 <= moveIndex){
            return false;
    }
    if (startIndex >= endIndex){
            return false;
    }

    LinkedListNode<T> startNode = list.ElementAt(startIndex);
    LinkedListNode<T> endNode = list.ElementAt(endIndex);

    LinkedListNode<T> restMoveNode = null;
    LinkedListNode<T> insertAfterNode;
    if (moveIndex < list.Count) {
            //when not inserting at the end of the list
            restMoveNode = list.ElementAt(moveIndex);
            insertAfterNode = restMoveNode.Previous;
    } else {
            //when inserting at the end of the list
            insertAfterNode = list.ElementAt(moveIndex - 1);
    }

    if (insertAfterNode == null){
            //when inserting at the beginning of the list 
            list.AddFirst(startNode);
    } else {    
            insertAfterNode.Next = startNode;
    }
    //restore previous list elements    
    endNode.next = restMoveNode;

    return true;
}
```

Although @jmyns already posted an answer with a linked list, I think my solution serves the idea of a linked list better.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping something like this in your own method:

```
List<int> subList = myList.GetRange(startIndex, count);
myList.RemoveRange(startIndex, count);
myList.InsertRange(insertionPoint, subList);
```

Comment: `insertionPoint` may move after the change.

Answer (score 0):

A linkedlist may be ideal, but it depends on how large your initial list is.  Each node has a pointer to the next, which makes for simple moves.  There is an added expense and many people prefer to use regular lists.

```
LinkedList<int> linked = new LinkedList<int>();
linked = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }
```

Declare the items you want to move in an array and remove them from myList

```
int [] itemsToMove = { 1, 2 };

for (int i = 0; i < itemsToMove -1; i++)
{
linked.Remove(itemsToMove[i])
}
```

Now linked will be

```
linked = { 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }
```

Identify target Node

```
LinkedListNode<int> targetNode = linked.Find("7");
```

Then iterate over the items adding the items after the target node.  If order is important reverse the array first.

```
Array.Reverse(itemsToMove);

for (int i = 0; i < itemsToMove.Length - 1; i++)
{
linked.AddAfter(targetNode , itemsToMove[i]);
}
```

Comment: Note that using a linked list would make this one operation easier, but it's likely that it would make many other operations that need to be performed on this collection (like say random access by index) much slower.